# MongoDB using aggregation compare two array id's and update time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB I have two arrays in the same document which have common `id` field. I would like to merge these two matching on id's and update the time value when there is a match.

```
mcq:[
{
id:1,
answer:A,
time:0
},
{
id:2,
answer:F,
time:0
},
{
id:3,
answer:A,
time:0
},
{
id:4,
answer:B,
time:0
}
]

activity:[
{
id:1,
time:21.2
},
{
id:3,
time:10.3
}
]
```

I want the final array to have the time updated from `activity` if there is a match in `id`

```
final=[
    {
    id:1,
    answer:A,
    time:21.2
    },
    {
    id:2,
    answer:F,
    time:0
    },
    {
    id:3,
    answer:A,
    time:10.3
    }
    {
    id:4
    answer:B,
    time:0
    }
    ]
```

I have tried using below in aggregation but am getting the same time for all id's

```
{
    '$addFields': {
      'final': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$mcq', 
          'as': 'c', 
          'in': {
            'id': '$$c.id', 
            'time': {
              '$arrayElemAt': [
                '$activity.time', {
                  '$indexOfArray': [
                    '$activity.id', '$$c.id'
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }, 
            'answer': '$$c.answer'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$map` to iterate look of `mcq`,
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `activity`, set `mcq.time` as initial value, check condition if id match then return time, otherwise return initial value,
- back to `$map`, merge current object and `time` field using `$mergeObjects`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      mcq: {
        $map: {
          input: "$mcq",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$m",
              {
                time: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$activity",
                    initialValue: "$$m.time",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.id", "$$m.id"] }, "$$this.time", "$$value"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3diTcTsbJFI)