# Pymongo $match using _ids and project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

New to Pymongo and I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423451/16629499).
My query is this:

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "combcolltier": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$educations",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$m",
              {
                "tier": {
                  "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$collegetiers",
                    "initialValue": "$$m.tier",
                    "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                        {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$this._id",
                            "$$m.collegeId"
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$this.tier",
                        3
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And an example of my collection is:

```
'educations': [{'sharedStatus': 0,
    '_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4ej4he03250e69'),
   },
   {'sharedStatus': 2,
    '_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4eu5uu03250e6a'),
    'profileTypeId': ObjectId('5e8gh64f1e9f5261ae56e41')}]

'collegetiers': [{'_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4eu5uu03250e6a'),
    'status': True,
    'image': 'masters/college/Birla+Vishwakarma+Mahavidyalaya.png'},
   {'_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4ej4he03250e69'),
    'status': True,
    'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 12, 12, 6, 8, 67000),
    'tier': 2,
    'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 12, 12, 6, 8, 67000)}],
```

Desired result would be something that matches on the basis of Id's and college Id's and returns the "tier" or 3.
Something like this:

```
'combined_field': [{'sharedStatus': 0,
    '_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4ej4he03250e69'),
    'tier':2
   },
   {'sharedStatus': 2,
    '_id': ObjectId('5e7250c58a4eu5uu03250e6a'),
    'profileTypeId': ObjectId('5e8gh64f1e9f5261ae56e41'),
    'tier':3}]
```

Version of MongoDB is 4.4.4

Comment: Are `educations` and `collegetiers` two collections or two arrays in the same collection?

Comment: They are two collections that I've projected using `$lookup`. I tried using `$pipeline` to get the above result but it took way too much time for the same

Comment: You are mapping over the documents in the `educations` array, and trying to use `collegeId` and `tier` fields, which don't exist in those documents.